# Ruby Facets 2.9.0 work with Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby Facets 2.9.0 work with Ruby 1.9.2?

Cause I can't get rekey method to work: http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Hash.html#method-i-rekey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can find out if a ruby library is 1.9 compatible by checking http://isitruby19.com/

It looks like other people have used Facets as early as version 2.5.0, and as recent as 2.8.1.

http://isitruby19.com/facets

Comment: There was one more site similar to this one. But I can't remember the name.

Comment: @ajsie: Are you referring to railsplugins.org , or isitjruby.com, which is no longer running?